# Android show toast message when last 30 seconds of video is left

Tags: android, video, duration, exoplayer

I am Playing video on Android using EXO player. I want to show toast message to user when last 30 second of video is left. How to get notified when last 30 seconds of video is left?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the current position and duration of the video you can use `getCurrentPosition()` and  `getDuration();`, on the `ExoPlayer` instance. Both are in milliseconds. When the difference is `<= 30000` you can show your pop up. How and how often you should check if this condition is true it is up to you. I would use an Handler if I were in you

Comment: is there any other option rather than using Handler to get notified?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code as following:

```
TrackRenderer tr;
If (tr.getDurationUs() - tr.getMediaClock().getPositionUs() <= 30000)
{
    showToast();
}
```

Above should show toast when 30 secs of video is left.

Note: TrackRenderer.getDurationUs() and getPositionUs() returns microseconds in long type.